# Angular binding model property to ng-click not passing value to MVC controller method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a calendar with events on it, each having a distinct EventId.  When a user clicks an event, it triggers an angular controller method which in turn gets the data for the event via an MVC controller and displays it on the page.  I also have a button on the page that when clicked should open up a modal to edit the details of the data being displayed and I am using data binding to set the URL for the modal window.  The data-ng-click attribute of the button looks like this:

```
data-ng-click="app.modal.OpenModalWindow({ template: '[my url here]/?eventId={{vm.EventId}}' })"
```

In the markup I see this:

```
data-ng-click="app.modal.OpenModalWindow({ template: '[my url here]/?eventId=18' })"
```

but when I click the button, the browser is trying to do the following (from the Chrome Network tab in dev tools):

```
GET [my url here]/?eventId={{vm.EventId}} 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

If I take the URL from the markup or hard-code the eventId everything works fine so I know it is not the OpenModalWindow so I'm thinking it is some sort of binding issue.  I have placed {{vm.EventId}} on the page and know that it is getting set properly, but somehow this is not getting to my model.

The error I am getting back is that the parameter "eventId" in my MVC controller cannot be null, which makes sense because I'm sending it a string with the value "{{vm.EventId}}" but the param type is an int.  Its like my markup is getting updated, but the data bound to the click event is not.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!